# How to get the Date from Time Stamp

Tags: excel, vba

am having one Excel file it contains the data with multiple sheets. In that One column having time stamp like 21/6/12 10:33:07:AM. My system date format is "m/d/yyyy"
while converting this to Date 21/06/2012. am able to get the date but it is showing in wrong. 06-12-2021 this should be 21-06-2012. am using the below code.

Ex : 26/6/12 11:15:07:AM should be 26/06/2012
     21/6/12 10:33:07:AM should be 21/06/2012

```
Public Sub ConvtDate()
Dim ParseDateTime As Date
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each datcol In ws_Raw2.Range("I2:I65536")  
x = InStr(1, datcol, " ", vbTextCompare) - 1  
If x > 0 Then  
    ParseDateTime = DateValue(Left(datcol, x))  
    datcol.Value = ParseDateTime
End If  
Next  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub
```

Please help how to get the date.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateValue` expects a date as a string in the format set by your system.
From Excel Help:

> If date is a string that includes only numbers separated by valid date separators, DateValue recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to the Short Date format you specified for your system.

Since your data is in `Day Month Year` and your system is `Month Day Year` you will need to reconstruct the parameter you pass to `DateValue`.

Here's a refactor of your coed, also dealing with a few other issues:

- `Dim` *all* your variables (use `Option Explicit` to force this)
- Only process rows you need to
- Loop a variant array rather than a range, it *much* faster

---

```
Public Sub ConvtDate()
    Dim ParseDateTime As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim a() As String
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    dat = rng.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        x = InStr(1, dat(i, 1), " ", vbTextCompare) - 1
        If x > 0 Then
            a = Split(Left(dat(i, 1), x), "/")
            ParseDateTime = DateValue(a(1) & "/" & a(0) & "/" & a(2))
            ' or if you dont know the system data format use
            ' ParseDateTime = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))
            dat(i, 1) = ParseDateTime
        End If
    Next
    rng = dat
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  
But the code is looping (iterating) only one time

Comment: For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
can you please help how to resolve this.

Comment: Oops, a typo... should be `For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1) `

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it worked like a charm...   if we dont know the system date format, is there anyway to do this ? is the only way to identify the system date format and do the formating

Comment: You couls use `ParseDateTime = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))` instead

Comment: Thanks Chris for the quick response and the entire help.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will change 26/6/12 to 26/06/2012 itself if the column formating ins date. So

```
ParseDateTime = Left(datcol, x)
```

should do it.

Comment: But it is changing to 12/06/2026. instead of 06/26/2012